# Can we map the custom index tags of blob document inside azure storage container to azure cognitive search?

Tags: azure-cognitive-search

We are tagging the documents uploaded to the storage container to be searched by the particular tag in the cognitive search, we could find that custom metadata properties can be linked to search index field with the same name, but this case is not true with custom tags, is there any way to map the custom tags to search index field through indexer.

Comment: I'm guessing the tags are open-ended and not known to you in advance?

Answer (score 0):

Metadata tags on blob properties can be used within an indexer under "fieldMappings". It's important to note that this works using metadata tags, not tags. Add the key names to your index fields and check casing is correct on keys as they can/are lower-case after a set operation.

Note that field mappings are necessary unless key/value and applying it to another index field. If the field name doesn't change, adding the property as a field to the index only is enough -or- if an operation such as base64decode/encode is necessary.

Validate tags are present using storage explorer.
[image: tags under metadata]

Updating the index json to add the field:

```
{
  "name": "somemetadatatag",
  "type": "Edm.String",
  "searchable": true,
  "filterable": true,
  "retrievable": true,
  "sortable": true,
  "facetable": true,
  "key": false,
  "indexAnalyzer": null,
  "searchAnalyzer": null,
  "analyzer": null,
  "normalizer": null,
  "synonymMaps": []
}
```

Full documentation here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/search/search-howto-indexing-azure-blob-storage